# Objective-C casting

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to cast this statement:

```
[self handError:noConnectionError];
```

basically, this statement is in a class, which is not the app delegate, but is the .m file of a view, specifically a view after uitableview, which contains its own uiviewtable.

The warning that statement gives me is that the error produced may not be apparent to the UIView (view control container).

Comment: What are you asking? Unclear from your question what the error is, and exactly what you're calling that's returning that error. Or is it a compiler error? What are you casting?

Comment: I'm recieving warning: "NTItemsList may not respond to handleError:". I'd like to know how to resolve that, and that I understand that this can be done through casting?

Comment: Show some code so your question is made clearer with context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the objective-c compiler telling you that the method is not declared in the interface for the class.   Add the method declaration to the .h file and the warning should go away.

Also, if you want the method to be private, you can extend the interface in the .m file with a category like

```
@interface NTItemList (PrivateMethods)
 - (void)handleError:(NSError *)error;
@end
```

This has the added benifit of not cluttering your class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with casting as far as I can tell. It would appear that your class does not implement `handleError:`, which is required if you want to send it that message.